# Using git rebase to skip some directories or files

Tags: git

I would love your help with git rebase command. I have a directory **ParentDir** which contains **UI**, **SEVER**, and other files. So, I was working in `develop branch` but I want to checkout to `gh-pages` and get the updated code from `develop` branch.

I know how to use ***git rebase*** command but it comes with all the directories and files from the ***develop*** branch.

Is there any way to ignore/skip other files and directories and just grab the **UI** directory from `develop` into `gh-pages`? Thanks.

Comment: in new branch, you want that there's not any files but UI?

Comment: @yelliver, absolutely yes.

Comment: If you have one (or several) commits that ONLY implement UI and nothing else, then you can cherry pick these specific commits onto `gh-pages`

Comment: @mnestorov, how? any git command for that?

Comment: @Mo1 you can use `git cherry-pick`. Check the documentation but basically go to your desired branch and cherry pick the commit hashes you want to transfer to `gh-pages`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you asked how to get a group of files, and for some reason people keep answering that with "how to get changes from specific commits'.

But that's still going to get you *all changes to all files* from those commits. Depending on your history, you may or may not be able to make that work; but only under very specific circumstances is that the easiest way.

And more specifically, the cases where `cherry-pick` would be a good solution are a subset of the cases where `rebase` would work well.  Since you say you know `rebase` and couldn't get the result you want that way, I'm assuming you have a case where neither `rebase` nor `cherry-pick` is a good option[1].

If the changes you want are mixed in with other changes in the same commits, then commands that operate on commits (like rebase or cherry-pick) won't do what you want.  In that case there are several very different approaches, and which makes sense depends on what you're really trying to accomplish.

The most direct way to do literally what you asked is

```
git checkout gh-branch
git checkout develop -- ./UI
```

(If the changes include deletes, you might need an extra step, e.g.

```
git checkout gh-branch
rm -r ./UI
git checkout develop -- ./UI
```

for the deletes to be "seen".)

Then your worktree is in the state you say you want, and you can commit that.  But this will again put your branch in conflict with develop, and since it's not based on exact duplicate commits, git will have a harder time helping with automatic resolution later.

---

[1] I will point out, just in case, that the most general way to solve the problem with `rebase` is to do an *interactive rebase*.  You would be rebasing commits *from* develop *onto* `gh-branch`.

```
git checkout --detach develop
git rebase -i gh-branch
# edit the todo list to `pick` the commits with the changes you want

# and once the rebase is done, update gh-branch in any of a number of ways; one of the "safest" being
git tag gh-branch-temp
git checkout gh-branch
git merge --ff-only gh-branch-temp
git tag -d gh-branch-temp
```

If you haven't tried that approach, you could look into it, as it's a *much* easier/less error-prone approach that gets the same effect as `cherry-pick`; which is the main reason I consider `cherry-pick` to be wildly over-recommended.

But be aware - if you're trying to work 'as though' you had done the UI work on a branch, neither rebase nor cherry-pick will get you there; the `develop` branch remains as-is.  The changes that remain on `develop` will be in conflict with your branch (though git will make a pretty good effort to auto-resolve the conflicts when they come up down the road, it may not be able).

Comment: thanks for your input. I'll try your solution and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all changes in develop without changes of UI?

If you have a commit with only implements the UI, and another with the changes that you want, you can:

git checkout hashcommitwithoutUIchanges

git checkout -b gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, use `git log` to see exactly which commit you want to pick
  then use the following to cherry pick flow.

`git checkout -b gh-pages`

- then use the hash you want to pick up

`git cherry-pick 9638d9`

- In some cases picking one single commit is not enough. You need, let’s say three consecutive commits.
  cherry-pick is not the right tool for this. rebase is.
- In that case follow this article [git cherry pick](https://www.devroom.io/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/)