# How to exclude some directory when doing rebase from master

Tags: git, rebase

I have branched checked out of master branch. let say branch1, i have added changes to branch1 comitted and pushed changed. Now after 1 year, i have to rebase from master and while rebasing i want to exclude some directory. I want to keep those directories untouched while rebasing, how can we do that?

for example : branch1 has folder1, folder2 , folder3, folder4 . and same structure exists in master branch also. Now I don't want folder3 to get affected (Want to keep code from branch1 only) when doing rebase from master.

Comment: This question has [already been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57807120/3833426).

Comment: I would stash the modifications of folder3 before commit and rebase

Comment: How is `folder3` affected in `branch1` since the branch diverged from `master`?

Comment: Rather.... can you add the output of this command in the question? `git diff --name-status master...branch1 -- folder1 folder3` (make sure it's 3 dots, not 2).

Comment: So, what you want to do is, **after rebase**, to _keep_ the same content that `folder3` had on `branch1` before you rebased _regardless_ of any changes that were introduced in `folder3` in `branch1...master`?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no changes introduced on `branch3` since `branch1` diverged from `master` then rebase **won't** mess with it while rebasing `branch1` on top of `master`. If there are changes done on `folder3` on `master` that you would like to **discard** so that you keep that directory the way it is in `branch1` before it is rebased, then you should create a new commit just for that and then rebase.

```
git checkout master
git rm --cached folder3 # no worries, we are about to get it back
git checkout branch1 -- folder3 # get the contents of the directory just like it is in branch1
git commit -m "Getting folder3 the way it is in branch1 before rebasing it" # set a proper comment there
git rebase master branch1
```

Now you can be sure that `folder3` is just like it was on `master1` before rebase.

If **there are changes** on both branches and you would like to keep the content of the directory as it is on `branch1`, then we need to revert the changes done on `master` on `folder3` so that the rebase does not complain in any step:

```
git checkout master
git rm folder3 # no worries, we will get it back
git checkout $( git merge-base branch1 master) -- folder3
git commit -m "Getting folder3 the way it was when we started working on branch1" # set a proper message
git rebase master branch1
```

That should work and you should have `folder3` with the same content of `branch1` *before* rebase.

Comment: folder3 has lot many changes in branch1 than master. so we don't want to messup and resolve conflict. So checking if there is any better solution to directly exclude that folder. and 1 thing in mind we never merge that branch1 chnages to master again for long time. we kept it as seprate branch.

Comment: and Now after long time we want to sync up with master again, without overwriting folder3 content.

Comment: Oh... man.... then more effort will be required.... let me think about it for a few minutes to see what would be the simplest approach.

Comment: What I am not clear right now is which content would you like to keep in `branch1` after rebasing in `folder3`? The content as it is in `branch1` originally or the content of `master` without touching it? This wording allows for the confusion: `Now I don't want folder3 to get affected (Want to keep code from branch1 only) when doing rebase from master.`

Comment: I want original content of folder3 from branch1